# Send mutableListOf<Int>() ( included 2 parameters ) to another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have this code in activity A :

```
private fun randomImage() {
        val number: Int = (1..4).random()
        if (!selectedImageList.contains(number)) selectedImageList.add(number)
        if (selectedImageList.size == 2) return
        else randomImage()
    }
```

and have this code in activity B :

```
     private fun setImages(binding: ActivityP1Binding) {

        selectedImageList.forEachIndexed { index, number ->

            when (number) {
                1 -> {
                    if (index == 0) binding.a1.setImageResource(R.drawable.Omo1)
                    if (index == 1) binding.b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.Omo1)
                }
                2 -> {
                    if (index == 0) binding.a1.setImageResource(R.drawable.Omo2)
                    if (index == 1) binding.b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.Omo2)
                }
                3 -> {
                    if (index == 0) binding.a1.setImageResource(R.drawable.Omo3)
                    if (index == 1) binding.b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.Omo3)
                }
                4 -> {
                    if (index == 0) binding.a1.setImageResource(R.drawable.Omo4)
                    if (index == 1) binding.b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.Omo4)
                }
```

So It needs codes to send selectedImageList ( included index and number ) from activity A . And codes to receive in activity B . I used some Codes to intent by putParcelableArrayListExtra , but they did not work .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like all you need to do is send an array of integers from activity A to activity B. This can be done with putExtra (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#putextra_17) and getIntArrayExtra (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#getintarrayextra)

See https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-list-to-array-kotlin/ for converting a List to an Array

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way it will definitely work
So in activity A, add this code in intent part

```
intent.putExtra("tag",ArrayList(selectedImageList))
```

and in Activity B,

```
val my_List=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("tag") as ArrayList
```

and you will receive a ArrayList of your values in Activity B